# why can't puppeteer scrape an element from a iframe even if I add the selector

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I have written a small web scraper using puppeteer, but I can't seem to properly extract the information I want. Could you please help me find the mistake?

Background: I want to scrape a website that indicates how much of premium the city allows a landlord to add to rest controlled apartments (e.g. for a prime location).

What I have done so far (Code below):
I am able to navigate through the site, access the iframe, write some input, click a button and get a resulting summary form. I want to extract the date and euro values of the first two rows and save it to a json. Ultimately, I want to do this for a bunch of addresses (still need to check how I can easily do this) and then aggregate this info (difference in the premium to the previous period etc).

The Problem:
I can Isolate the selectors for the relevant infos I want, but using frame.$$eval or frame.$ delivers nothing (but runs through without error). So I used waitForSelector which timed out and frame.evaluate threw an error. It was all very weird. My next approach was to scrape the whole form/summary - this worked! When I printed the object to the console, I had one long character string with everything on the page, including my info. However, this was highly unstructured and I couldn't figure out how to work with it to isolate my info. In addition, I couldn't save it to the json file (only a portion of the text was saved).

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const chalk = require("chalk");
const fs = require('fs');
const error = chalk.bold.red;
const success = chalk.keyword("green");

(async () => {
  try {
    // open the headless browser
      var browser = await puppeteer.launch({slowMo: 250});

    // open a new page
      var page = await browser.newPage();

    // enter url in page
      await page.goto(`https://mein.wien.gv.at/Meine-Amtswege/richtwert?subpage=/lagezuschlag/`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
   // continue without newsletter
      await page.click('#dss-modal-firstvisit-form > button.btn.btn-block.btn-light');
   // let everyhting load
      await page.waitFor(5000)
      console.log('waiting for iframe with form to be ready.');
      //wait until selector is available
      await page.waitForSelector('iframe');
      console.log('iframe is ready. Loading iframe content');
      //choose the relevant iframe
      const elementHandle = await page.$(
          'iframe[src="/richtwertfrontend/lagezuschlag/"]',
      );
      //go into frame in order to input info
      const frame = await elementHandle.contentFrame();
      //enter address
      console.log('filling form in iframe');
      await frame.type('#input_adresse', 'Gumpendorfer Straße 12, 1060 Wien', { delay: 1000 });

      //choose first option from dropdown
      console.log('Choosing from dropdown');
      await frame.click('#react-autowhatever-1--item-0');

      console.log('pressing button');
      //press button to search
      await frame.click('#next-button');

      // scraping data
      console.log('scraping')
      const optionsResult = await frame.$$eval('#summary', (options) => {
          const result = options.map(option => option.textContent);
          return result;
            });

    console.log(optionsResult);

   await browser.close();

          fs.writeFile("data.json", JSON.stringify(optionsResult), 'utf8', function(err) {
            if(err) {
                return console.log(error(err));
            }
            console.log(success("The data has been scraped and saved successfully! View it at './data.json'"));
        });

    console.log(success("Browser Closed"));
  } catch (err) {
      // Catch and display errors
      console.log(error(err));
      await browser.close();
      console.log(error("Browser Closed"));
    }


})();
```

I am posting the whole code for completion, the important bit is the "scraping" section starting on line 45.

I have perused SO and read many different threads but haven't yet found the solution. I hope everything is clear and I would appreciate any help!

PS I am quite new with JS/node.js/puppeteer so apologies if there are some inaccuracies and I don't know the ins and outs of the language yet.

Comment: Question: instead of loading the website and struggling with the iframe, why don't you page.goto( the_iframe_address ) ?

Comment: interesting point. I did not know that that was possible - thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some considerations.

1. `await frame.type('#input_adresse', 'Gumpendorfer Straße 12, 1060 Wien', { delay: 1000 });` — 1000 seems too long, maybe 100 or even 50 will suffices.
2. Prefer `innerText` to `textContent` to get more readable content.
3. This is how you can get more structured data, multidimensional array with rows and cells:

```js
      // scraping data
      console.log('scraping')
      await frame.waitForSelector('#summary > div > div > br ~ div');
      const optionsResult = await frame.evaluate(() => {
        const rows = [...document.querySelectorAll('#summary > div > div > br ~ div')];
        const cells = rows.map(
          row => [...row.querySelectorAll('div')]
                   .map(cell => cell.innerText)
        );
        return cells;
      });
```

Comment: This solved the problem perfectly - thank you very much for your help! Re the delay in frame.type: I wasn't sure what would be good time so I made it really long on purpose just to be sure.